# Generating 3D Gaussian random distribution

Tags: algorithms, random

I was coding a function to generate a 3D Gaussian distribution. However, I obtain unexpected results.

My idea was to generate these numbers $(x,y,z)$ through the following procedure:

1. Generate three uniformly distributed numbers $r_0\in[0,1]$, $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, and $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$;
2. Use the transformation $r = \sqrt{-\log r_0}$; and
3. Use spherical coordinates as
   $$\begin{align} 
   x &= r \sin\theta \cos\phi \\ 
   y &= r \sin\theta \sin\phi \\
   z &= r \cos\theta 
   \end{align}$$

After running this algorithm several times, the distribution of $z$ is effectively gaussian, but the distributions of $x$ and $y$ are not (see following figure). What am I missing?

[image: random numbers]

By the way, I coded this algorithm with Fortran:

```
subroutine rand_maxwellian(xx, yy, zz)
   implicit none

   real, intent(out) :: xx, yy, zz
   real :: pi = acos(-1), rr, th, ph                                                                                                                                             

   call random_seed()
   call random_number(th)        ! theta  = [0,1]                                                                                                                     
   call random_number(ph)        ! phi    = [0,1]                                                                                                                       
   call random_number(rr)        ! radius = [0,1]                                                                                                                       

   th = pi*th                    ! theta = [0,pi]                                                                                                                     
   ph = 2.0*pi*ph                ! phi = [0,2pi]                                                                                                                        
   rr = sqrt( -log(rr) )         ! radius in a gaussian distribution                                                                                                    

   xx = rr * sin(th) * cos(ph)                                                                                                                                          
   yy = rr * sin(th) * sin(ph)                                                                                                                                          
   zz = rr * cos(th)                                                                                                                                                    
end subroutine rand_maxwellian
```

Answer (score 1):

(Answering this old post since I was searching for the answer myself and found it.)

Rather than using spherical coordinates, you could use:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method

Take a random point uniformly in the cube [-1,1]^3. If it is further than 1 from the origin, discard and try again. Once you have such a point, adjust the radius as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you use is mimicking the standard 2D way to construct such Gaussians. And indeed $z$ is Gaussian and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the abs value of a Gaussian (you may check this numerically). But multiplying the latter with $\cos \phi$ and $\sin \phi$ does not produce Gaussians.